# Kernel module write to proc does not work

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to handle the **writting operation** on my `proc` module, but the pointer function is not working.

When execute `cat` on the file, `dmesg` command shows the **pr_info** defined on `my_read` function

```sh
$ cat /proc/myprocfile
$ sudo dmesg | grep 'my_read'
[ 5788.919508] myprocfile my_read handler
```

But when try to write on the file, `dmesg` command never shows the **pr_info** defined on `my_write` function

```sh
$ echo 1 > /proc/myprocfile
$ sudo dmesg | grep 'my_write'
```

My module

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/version.h>

#define FILE_NAME "myprocfile"

static struct proc_dir_entry *my_proc_file;

static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    pr_info("%s my_read handler\n", FILE_NAME);
    return -1;
}

static ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    pr_info("%s my_write handler\n", FILE_NAME);
    return -1;
}

static const struct proc_ops proc_file_fops = {
    .proc_read = my_read,
    .proc_write = my_write
};

static int __init proc_init(void)
{
    my_proc_file = proc_create(
        FILE_NAME,
        0644,
        NULL,
        &proc_file_fops
    );

    return 0;
}

static void __exit proc_exit(void)
{
    proc_remove(my_proc_file);
}

module_init(proc_init);
module_exit(proc_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This is my Makefile

```
obj-m += proc_test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

My kernel version is **5.11.0-40-generic**

Comment: Try calling `printk` directly.

Comment: Nope, it's still not printing the log message.

Comment: I've resolved the problem, it was a permission issue. Just changed value 0644 to 0666 on ``proc_create`` function.
``my_proc_file = proc_create(FILE_NAME, 0666, NULL, &proc_file_fops);``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue, just changed the value of permissions from 0644 to 0666 on `proc_create_function`.

```c
static int __init proc_init(void)
{
    my_proc_file = proc_create(
        FILE_NAME,
        0666, // Updated value
        NULL,
        &proc_file_fops
    );

    return 0;
}
```